# ui:InputDate Lightning summer 17 changes

Tags: lightning, summer-17

I know salesforce summer 17 release depricated ui:inputcomponent.
We have a date picker with ui:inputdate and it was broke in a summer 17 sandbox. We were working on a fix in spring sandbox, but figured out that the date picker works fine now. Did salesforce bring ui:dateinput back again? I don't see any document anywhere? did anything change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Summer 17, there are two issues that will affect you:

1. Locale has been removed from all `localizationService` calls.

> The locale parameter is deprecated for several methods in the AuraLocalizationService object. The validation for the locale parameter has also been tightened to allow locale values to match only the user’s Language or Locale settings in Salesforce. If the locale parameter is set to another value, it defaults to the user’s Language setting.

2. `ui:inputDate` has changes, described here:

> The behavior of the date picker has changed.
>   Clicking the date field displays the date picker even if displayDatePicker is false. If displayDatePicker is true, an icon that triggers the date picker is displayed in the field.
>   The date picker displays the Today link. Press the link to set today’s date on the date field.

How this will affect you:

- You have a Summer 17 sandbox with the changed `locale` and
  `ui:inputDate` component.
- You have a Spring 17 Production instance.
- You can't deploy these changes until Summer 17 is officially
  released, as the `locale` issue will affect you.
- You DO however have to deploy as soon as Summer 17 goes live, because
  your existing date picker will immediately break.

Salesforce never took away `ui:inputDate` or brought it back - it's always been there, but is now not useable for the custom date picker, as it tries to use it's own built in, horrible looking date picker.

The custom datepicker you are using **NO LONGER USES** `ui:inputDate` - it uses a custom inputdate that I built. Which is why it all works now.

Ref [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_lightning_locale_api.htm?edition=&impact=) and [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_lightning_components.htm?edition=&impact=)

Comment: I have a local sandbox which is summer 17 preview. The date picker was broke in that sandbox because it was summer 17. Now without any chnages to it, it is working as it used to without any summer 17 impacts. How is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't really tell without looking at the org. However, that aside, I think the situation that will occur is as I've described above. There is one possibility however... perhaps Salesforce decided not to proceed with the change to the `ui:datePicker`... which is annoying as I had to make myself a whole new component to get around the issue. Time will tell.